# error: expected primary-expression before '<<' token en c++

Tags: c++

Necesito ayuda con esta programación de c++
[image: [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio. Por favor, [no publiques imágenes con código fuente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21), copia y pega directamente el código en tu pregunta. NO olvides incluir de la misma manera mensajes exactos de error. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Es mas fácil responder cuando ingresas código en vez de imágenes, pero en este caso el problema es muy sencillo. En las lineas 13, 15, 17 y 19 tienes ; (punto y coma) extras justo después de cerrar las comillas.